# Is the [emit] tag providing any use or structure?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Is the [emit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emit) (x59) tag providing any use whatsoever?

All questions in it are related to different things and the definition for it isn't even set.
People are referencing to C#, Mongo, Ruby and entirely different functions.

Should this exist? Is there any purpose in a tag that isn't used to identify a specific thing but a common function name that could mean anything?

Comment: This is a classic burninate-request for a meta-tag. FTFY. Anyway, you are right, get the dragon!

Comment: Cheers. Noticed it before. Bit silly :)

Comment: They are [reflection.emit] questions.  [emit] should probably be a synonym.

Comment: @HansPassant other people are already using emit for other questions so making it a synonym would invalidate the other questions I'd imagine.

Comment: Well, isn't that what you had in mind anyway?  At least you'll catch the good ones.

Comment: I'm quite new to StackOverflow (you can probably tell from my rep) so I'm not sure what you'd do. would it be better to make it a synonym and then edit all the questions where emit isn't relevant?

Comment: Well, it will be abused in the future , so burnination is the only way to prevent it. Synonyming won't help.

Comment: Now down to (x37).  I moved all questions about `Reflection.Emit` to [reflection.emit].  Also found one [emitmapper] question.  Some of the others seem to be about various libraries that have an `.emit()` function (so they should have the tag removed), but I have not read through all of them.

Answer (score 2):

How does this tag help describe the question? How can anyone be an expert in emitting?

Let it burn.